# Too Much Data for SVM?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

So I'm running a SVM classifier (with a linear kernel and probability false) from sklearn on a dataframe with about 120 features and 10,000 observations. The program takes hours to run and keeps crashing due to exceeding computational limits. Just wondering if this dataframe is perhaps too large?

Comment: That should be ok for a linear kernel (at least with LinearSVC; not sure about SVC with kernel=linear). Show us the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing the parameters for the algorithm.

[Tips on practical use from the documentation.](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#tips-on-practical-use)

You could try a different algorithm, here's a cheat sheet you might find helpful:

[image]

Comment: He is using a linear kernel, so there is no kernel-cache (in use)!

Comment: And the cheat-sheet exactly recommends what he is doing (classification < 100k samples -> linear SVC). So there is nothing to gain with this information.

Comment: Might k nearest neighbours perform better in this instance?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful diagram! So I guess 10,000 isn't too much after all, I'll have to try it again as well as KNeighbors with some parameter tweaking maybe.

Answer (score 2):

In short **no**, this is not too big at all. Linear svm can scale much further. The libSVC library on the other hand cannot. The good thing, even in scikit-learn you do have large scale svm implementation - LinearSVC which is based on [liblinear](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/). You can also solve it using SGD (also available in scikitlearn) which will converge for much bigger datasets as well.

Answer (score 0):

> The implementation is based on libsvm. The fit time complexity is more
>   than quadratic with the number of samples which makes it hard to scale
>   to dataset with more than a couple of 10000 samples.

The offical data about [sklearn svm](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn-svm-svc) told the theshold is 10,000 samples
so SGD could be a better try.